# Accessing struct via pointer in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, jnienv

"Simple" question put short:

Why exactly does

```
JNIEnv *g_env = NULL;
(*g_env)->ExceptionDescribe(g_env);
```

compile in gcc (C)

but not 
in g++ (C++)

```
error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘JNIEnv’ {aka ‘JNIEnv_’}
```

As I am working mainly with C++ I don't see why it should compile. As stated by the error, dereferencing the pointer will yield a "variable" and not a pointer anymore. I.e.: in C++ it would be either

```
g_env->ExceptionDescribe
```

or

```
(*g_env).ExceptionDescribe
```

as its not `JNIEnv **`

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. They may have a common ancestor and sometimes similar syntax, but most of the time the semantics are very different. For example, C++ have much stricter type-checking than C. What is valid in C might not be valid in C++, or the other way around.

Comment: Does the definition of `JNIEnv` vary depending on language used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your library code is different.

In C, `JNIEnv` is a pointer type:

```
typedef const struct JNINativeInterface *JNIEnv;
```

In C++, `JNIEnv` is a struct:

```
struct _JNIEnv;
typedef _JNIEnv JNIEnv;
```

So of course it will compile in one case and not in the other.

[Source](https://github.com/mapbox/jni.hpp/blob/8f55acd9017452f45a88ab3fb3aef89de995b723/test/android/jni.h#L139-L145)